# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getNamedAccounts' of 'hre' as it is undefined

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, dapps, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Currently attempting to deploy my smart contracts for a DAO DApp. When running:

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network localhost
```

I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getNamedAccounts' of 'hre' as it is undefined.
    at main (/Users/angelachaseling/Desktop/daoapp3/scripts/deploy.js:5:11)
```

Here is my deploy.js script:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { hre } = require('hardhat');

async function main() {
  const { getNamedAccounts, } = hre;
  const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts();


  // GovernanceToken
  const GovernorToken = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('GovernorToken');
  const governortoken = await GovernorToken.deploy(deployer);

  await governortoken.deployed();

  const contractsDir = __dirname + "/../pages/contractsData";
  if (!fs.existsSync(contractsDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(contractsDir);
  }

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governortoken-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: governortoken.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const GovernorTokenContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("GovernorToken");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governortoken.json`,
    JSON.stringify(GovernorTokenContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('GovernorToken deployed to:', governortoken.address);


  // TimeLock
  const Timelock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('Timelock');
  const timelock = await Timelock.deploy(deployer, 43200);

  await timelock.deployed();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/timelock-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: timelock.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const TimelockContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("Timelock");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/timelock.json`,
    JSON.stringify(TimelockContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('Timelock deployed to:', timelock.address);


  // GovernanceContract
  const GovernorContract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory('GovernorContract');
  const governorcontract = await GovernorContract.deploy(timelock.address, governortoken.address, deployer);

  await governorcontract.deployed();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governorcontract-address.json`,
    JSON.stringify({ address: governorcontract.address }, undefined, 2)
  );

  const GovernorContractArtifact = artifacts.readArtifactSync("GovernorContract");

  fs.writeFileSync(
    contractsDir + `/governorcontract.json`,
    JSON.stringify(GovernorContractArtifact, null, 2)
  );

  console.log('GovernorContract deployed to:', governorcontract.address);

}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Here is my hardhat.config.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
require("hardhat-deploy-ethers");

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('.secret').toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 200,
    },
  },
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainId: 31337,
      allowUnlimitedContractSize: true
    },
  },
};
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "daoapp3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.7.3",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.12",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "hardhat-deploy-ethers": "^0.3.0-beta.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^1.0.2",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "ethers": "^5.5.4",
    "hardhat": "^2.10.2",
    "hardhat-deploy-ethers": "^0.3.0-beta.13"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do either

```
const hre = require('hardhat')
const { getNamedAccounts } = hre
```

or

```
const { getNamedAccounts } = require('hardhat')
```

and then you can use `getNamedAccounts`.

Comment: I have made said changes, however I am still getting the error: `TypeError: getNamedAccounts is not a function`

Comment: Are you using hardhat-deploy-ethers? getNamedAccounts is implemented by this plugin, check: https://github.com/wighawag/hardhat-deploy-ethers, if you are using hardhat-ethers directly, you need to replace it with hardhat-deploy-ethers.

Comment: Yes, I've attached my hardhat.config.js to the bottom of my post, thankyou so much for your help so far, however I am still getting the same error, do you have any idea why?

Comment: What about package.json? is it imported something like: "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13", ?

Comment: No, I will attach my package.json below as well. I did have `npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers@^0.3.0-beta.13` installed at one point however I removed it from my package.json and installed hardhat-deploy-ethers

Comment: Try install as the github page recommends, it might have hardcoded dependency issues. And also make sure you import as require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
 in your hardhat.config.js

Answer (score 0):

in  your hardhad-config.js file please add the namedAccounts feild ..as it is not present in module.exports

```
 namedAccounts: {     
    deployer: {      
     default: 0,     
    } } ,
```

I guess it should work now,

Answer (score 0):

in  your hardhad-config.js file please add the namedAccounts feild ..as it is not present

```
 namedAccounts: {     
    deployer: {      
     default: 0,     
    } } ,
```

also please ensure that the following imports are there

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("dotenv").config()
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-deploy")
```

I guess it should work now,